# All lines of $\mathbb R^3$ are isometric to $\mathbb R$

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

I have just started reading Metric Spaces by Michael Searcoid. The first Chapter states a result :

> Suppose $n \in \mathbb N~\forall~ i \in \mathbb N_n,(X_i,\tau_i) $ is a non empty metric space. Let $e$ be a conserving metric on $P = \Pi_{i=1}^{n} X_i.$
>
> For each $j \in  \mathbb N_n, a \in P:$ let $ X_{j,a}= \{x \in P~|~x_i=a_i~\forall~i \in  \mathbb N_n-\{j\} \}$.
>
> Then, the map $x\rightarrow x_j$ is an isometry from $X_{j,a}$ to $X$.

By the above result, we get that certain lines of $\mathbb R^3$ parallel to an axis are isometric to $\mathbb R $.

However, the text goes on to say that all lines of $\mathbb R^3$ are isometric to $\mathbb R $ and gives the following reasoning :

> because for $a,b \in \mathbb R^3, b \ne 0, $ the map $t \rightarrow a + tb / \delta_{(0,0,0)}(b)$ from $\mathbb R$ onto $\{a + tb~|~t \in \mathbb R \}$ is an isometry.

I do not understand the immediate above reasoning ( especially, the term written as : $a + tb / \delta_{(0,0,0)}(b)$ ). Could somebody please help me understand this. Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

**Definitions used :**

Two spaces are isometric when an isometry between them exists.

On a given metric space :$~(X,d) ,  \delta_x (y) = \{ d(x,y)~\forall~y \in X ; x \in X \} $

Comment: Rotations and translations are isometries.  You could rotate the line and then translate it to an axis.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I am totally satisfied by thinking of rotations as symmetries as well. I am still a bit curious to know why would the text employ terminologies like the above :) Thanks again

Comment: :) $\delta_{(0, 0, 0)}$ is a terribly confusing way to denote distance from the origin.  Definitely looked like a kronecker delta to me.  Aha, but I see it is defined as such at the end of the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a+tb$, where $t$ ranges through $\mathbb R$, is a line.  But perhaps the map $t \mapsto a+tb$ is not an isometry.  Normalize by a certain factor to make it isometric.  That factor is the distance from the origin to $b$.

Comment: Thanks. I have a query please. If we suppose that the metric in $\mathbb R$ is $d_1$ and the metric in $\mathbb R^3$ is $d_2$. Then, for all lines in $\mathbb R^3$ to be isometric to $\mathbb R$, we should have $d_2 (a + t_1 \frac {b}{\delta_{(0,0,0)} b } , a + t_2  \frac {b}{\delta_{(0,0,0)} b } ) = d_1(t_1,t_2)$.

I think, if we define both the metrics as equal to the metric defined by euclidean norm, the two metrics will turn out to be equal. Am I correct? Do I have the freedom to choose such a metric? Thanks again

Comment: No, this does not work for most metrics.  I think the text probably means the Euclidean metric here.